# Dacpac database classic release deployment group not working.. but it says it is

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, dacpac

Been banging up against walls for the last few days on this:
I have a database project with pre and post deployment files. I build and copy those to my bin no issue. I have a pipeline that creates a .dacpac file for me.

I can verify the dacpac does the changes when I run this script locally via powershell:

```
# Define variables
$serverName = "'(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB'"
$databaseName = "_DB"
#$dacpacPath = "'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ohsrc_db/ohsrc_db\_DB.dacpac'"
$dacpacPath = "'C:\Projects\PHSA\OHSSolutions\API\OHSRC_DB\bin\Debug\_DB.dacpac'"

# Build the SQLPackage command
$sqlPackageCmd = "sqlPackage.exe"
$publishCmdArgs = "/Action:Publish /SourceFile:$dacpacPath /TargetDatabaseName:$databaseName /TargetServerName:$serverName /p:DropObjectsNotInSource='True'"

# Execute the SQLPackage command
Write-Output $publishCmdArgs
dotnet tool install -g microsoft.sqlpackage
Invoke-Expression  "$sqlPackageCmd $publishCmdArgs"
```

However after I am working with azure dev ops releases product where I am doing a classic release pipeline. I have tried taking the same as above (after changing source path)  but keep getting the following error:

```
2024-01-25T20:40:29.4261080Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2024-01-25T20:40:29.4444154Z ##[command]"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\azagent\A2\_work\_temp\a4cb565f-56b8-4cc0-b822-166849a904ed.ps1'"
2024-01-25T20:40:29.8057735Z /Action:Publish /SourceFile:'C:\azagent\A2\_work\r1\a/_db/_db/_DB.dacpac' /TargetDatabaseName:_DB /TargetServerName:'(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB' /p:DropObjectsNotInSource='True'
2024-01-25T20:40:30.0157286Z Tool 'microsoft.sqlpackage' is already installed.
2024-01-25T20:40:32.0795454Z Invoke-Expression : The term 'sqlPackage.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
2024-01-25T20:40:32.0795752Z operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
2024-01-25T20:40:32.0795946Z again.
2024-01-25T20:40:32.0796260Z At C:\azagent\A2\_work\_temp\a4cb565f-56b8-4cc0-b822-166849a904ed.ps1:17 char:1
2024-01-25T20:40:32.0796542Z + Invoke-Expression  "$sqlPackageCmd $publishCmdArgs"
2024-01-25T20:40:32.0796694Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-01-25T20:40:32.0797163Z     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sqlPackage.exe:String) [Invoke-Expression], CommandNotFoundException
```

setting the
$sqlPackageCmd = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\sqlPackage.exe"

results in more errors..

giving up sort of on this I try the traditional (since it is very traditional), of using the
Sql Server Dacpac deploy task . Tried both server and connection string. Same result where it says it works.. but actually doesn't work at all.

```
steps:
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Deploy _DB'
  inputs:
    DacpacFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_db/_db/_DB.dacpac'
    TargetMethod: connectionString
    ConnectionString: 'Data Source=(localDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=_DB;Integrated Security=True;'
    AdditionalArguments: '/DiagnosticsFile:$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/output.log'
```

and in this case it reports everything to be working.. however nothing actually worked... I am verifying this by doing new builds with pre and post deployment.. dropping tables , creating tables etc. Very frustrating.

```
2024-01-25T19:46:13.3819927Z Task         : SQL Server database deploy
2024-01-25T19:46:13.3819964Z Description  : Deploy a SQL Server database using DACPAC or SQL scripts
2024-01-25T19:46:13.3820016Z Version      : 0.198.0
2024-01-25T19:46:13.3820044Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2024-01-25T19:46:13.3820077Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group
2024-01-25T19:46:13.3820136Z ==============================================================================
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7909620Z Publishing to database '_DB' on server '(localDb)\MSSQLLocalDB'. 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7910039Z Initializing deployment (Start) 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7910244Z Initializing deployment (Complete) 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7910463Z Analyzing deployment plan (Start) 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7910674Z Analyzing deployment plan (Complete) 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7911350Z Updating database (Start) 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7911517Z Update complete. 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7911698Z Updating database (Complete) 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7911909Z Successfully published database. 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7912608Z Changes to connection setting default values were incorporated in a recent release.  More information is available at https://aka.ms/dacfx-connection 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7912941Z Time elapsed 0:00:14.60 
2024-01-25T19:46:30.7913050Z
```

Does anyone have a working powershell using a sqlpackage kind of like the way I am trying to? I don't want to migrate this to next environments until I can get it working locally.

------------UPDATE------------

I was super curious about the dacpac project that kept saying everything worked correctly so I went to the logs. within the logs is a path to the actual sql logs located at :

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB.error.log

Within that log file for the relevant deploy I see the following:

```
.... 
2024-01-25 14:06:49.19 Server      The service account is 'WORKGROUP\MACHINE NAME$'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.19 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -c
     -S "MSSQL15E.LOCALDB" <-- is it possible I am somehow connecting to a different instance of sql server? I am running version 19 / 2019
     -s "LOCALDB#DEDEC1FF"
     -d "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\master.mdf"
     -l "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\mastlog.ldf"
     -e "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\error.log"
...

2024-01-25 14:06:49.54 spid18s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.55 spid14s     Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.55 spid14s     The resource database build version is 15.00.4153. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.56 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.56 spid21s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.56 spid23s     Starting up database '_DB'. <--- This is my database that I cannot see 
2024-01-25 14:06:49.56 spid24s     Starting up database '_TESTDB'.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.58 spid14s     Starting up database 'model'.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.59 spid24s     Parallel redo is started for database '_TESTDB' with worker pool size [4]. <--- this was another test
2024-01-25 14:06:49.60 spid23s     Parallel redo is started for database '_DB' with worker pool size [4].
2024-01-25 14:06:49.60 spid24s     Parallel redo is shutdown for database '_TESTDB' with worker pool size [4].


BELOW YOU CAN SEE THE TRANSACTIONS APPLIED...however I can't see this db 
2024-01-25 14:06:49.60 spid23s     31 transactions rolled forward in database '_DB' (7:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.60 spid14s     Clearing tempdb database.

NO ROLLBACKS 
2024-01-25 14:06:49.61 spid23s     0 transactions rolled back in database '_DB' (7:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.61 spid23s     Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'OHSRC_DB' with worker pool size [4].
2024-01-25 14:06:49.65 spid14s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.78 spid21s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.78 spid21s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.80 spid21s     Service Broker manager has started.
2024-01-25 14:06:49.80 spid9s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-01-25 14:06:50.15 spid51      Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-01-25 14:06:50.16 spid51      Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2019.150.4153' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

below you can see a screenshot of the dbs that seem to be present in the ssms instance... so weird..
note: you do not see the foo database in the list above but it is below.
[image]

Comment: it looks to me like the agent you are running the script on does not have the sqlpackage.exe, or you are not pathing to it correctly. You can see the included software in the Microsoft hosted agents by following the `Included Software` link in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml , or if you are using self hosted agent, you may need to make sure it has the capabilities you are looking for, and you'll need to path to them correctly in your PowerShell script.

Comment: I am running the powershell on the same machine that is getting deployed to as the same machine the agent is running on.  That is not possible. It also has the step to install the sqlPackage as you can see but it says it is already installed.

Comment: 1. To resolve `The term 'sqlPackage.exe' is not recognized...` error, you need to add the path of sqlPackage.exe to your system environment variable and then restart the self-hosted agent. 2. According to the logs shared by you, the deployment using SQL Server database deploy task is successful. To narrow down the issue, please run `sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDBNew` to create a new local server named "MSSQLLocalDBNew" and run `sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDBNew` to start it. Then deploy to this brand new server via DevOps pipeline and check if there is the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your powershell task reports:

> Invoke-Expression : The term 'sqlPackage.exe' is not recognized as
> the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
> that the path is correct and try  again.

Check this link: [SqlPackage in development pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-pipelines?view=sql-server-ver16).

Try to use an explicit path: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\sqlPackage.exe`

or switch work-directory to: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\`

Comment: I'll try cd'ing into the SQL server directory. I had reviewed the link you gave already and I don't think I can apply it as I am using classic deploy steps. I can't edit the yaml directly.

Comment: @macm classic steps also contain this setting. Check `Advanced`->`Working Directory`